# woocommerce checkout option dropdown blue color problem

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't remove the blue color from the select dropdown option on the woocommerce checkout page. When you hover over the option, the blue color background comes below the text. Again, this blue color looks different in each browser .. How can this be overcome?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to use a variation of `-appearance: none` like `-webkit-appearance: none;` and `-moz-appearance: none` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: Not solve ! Any other idea ?

Answer (score -1):

The issue of styling select element dropdowns is established and essentially your options are very limited. To my knowledge, cross-browser custom stying is still not possible.

You will need to use JavaScript. The plugin I've been using successfully for a while is Choices.js https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices. This does add some overhead, but has a nice UX. Many alternatives are available and you could roll your own. To use Choices.js:

Install latest assets from CDN

```
<!-- Include base CSS (optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js/public/assets/styles/base.min.css"
/>

<!-- Include Choices CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js/public/assets/styles/choices.min.css"
/>

<!-- Include Choices JavaScript (latest) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"></script>
```

Add script to apply Choices

```
;(function($, document) {

    var $doc = $(document);

    $doc.ready(function() {
        initSelect();       
    });

    function initSelect() {
        if ($(".variations select").length) {
            var choices = new Choices(".variations select", {
                searchEnabled: false,
                shouldSort: false,
                itemSelectText: "",
            });
        }
    }

})(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: I did not down vote your answer, but possible reasons are: the code is untested because the OP did not give sufficient troubleshooting or a minimal example to work from; the answer is mainly offsite links, which could change or become 404s and thus be useless to future visitors. While this answer may be a path to an answer, it does not necessarily answer the question in full - because you can't really provide an answer, since OP doesn't provide enough information, so it's a guess.

Comment: @disinfor amended

Comment: Any others idea please...?